# Make non-elementor front-page.php editable with elementor

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am building a custom theme(classic) from scratch. Here is my front-page.php file:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Front Page
*/

 // Import the Elementor library
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/elementor/php/elementor.php' );

 // Initialize Elementor
 Elementor::start();
 
 // Get the existing content
 $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_queried_object_id() );
 
 // Append the content to the Elementor canvas
 Elementor::widget( 'custom_html', [
     'html' => $content
 ] );
 
 // Terminate Elementor
 Elementor::end();

get_header(); ?>

    <!-- header -->
    <header id = "header" class = "vh-100 carousel slide" data-bs-ride = "carousel" style = "padding-top: 104px;">
    <header id="header" class="vh-100 carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" 
        style="padding-top: 104px; 
            background: url(<?php echo get_theme_mod('header_background_image'); ?>) top/cover no-repeat;"
    >
        <!-- Calling the carousel items -->
        <div class="container h-100 d-flex align-items-center carousel-inner">
            <?php
                $carousel_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'carousel_item',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                );
                $carousel_query = new WP_Query($carousel_args);

                if ($carousel_query->have_posts()) {
                    $first_item = true;
                    while ($carousel_query->have_posts()) {
                        $carousel_query->the_post();
                        $h1_text = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'h1_text', true);
                        $h2_text = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'h2_text', true);
                        ?>

                        <div class="text-center carousel-item<?php if ($first_item) { echo ' active'; } ?>">
                            <h2 class="text-capitalize text-white"><?php echo $h2_text; ?></h2>
                            <h1 class="text-uppercase py-2 fw-bold text-white"><?php echo $h1_text; ?></h1>
                            <a href="#" class="btn mt-3 text-uppercase">shop now</a>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                        $first_item = false;
                    }
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>

        <button class = "carousel-control-prev" type = "button" data-bs-target="#header" data-bs-slide = "prev">
            <span class = "carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <button class = "carousel-control-next" type = "button" data-bs-target="#header" data-bs-slide = "next">
            <span class = "carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </header>
    <!-- end of header -->

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pages/collection', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pages/special', get_post_format() ); ?>
    
    
    <!-- offers -->
    <section id = "offers" class = "py-5">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center justify-content-lg-start text-lg-start">
                <div class = "offers-content">
                    <span class = "text-white">Discount Up To 40%</span>
                    <h2 class = "mt-2 mb-4 text-white">Grand Sale Offer!</h2>
                    <a href = "#" class = "btn">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end of offers -->
    
    
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pages/blog', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pages/about', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pages/popular', get_post_format() ); ?>

    <!-- newsletter -->
    <section id = "newsletter" class = "py-5">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class = "title text-center pt-3 pb-5">
                    <h2 class = "position-relative d-inline-block ms-4">Newsletter Subscription</h2>
                </div>

                <p class = "text-center text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus rem officia accusantium maiores quisquam dolorum?</p>
                <div class = "input-group mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email ...">
                    <button class = "btn btn-primary" type = "submit">Subscribe</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end of newsletter -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What i want to achieve is that, all the content in this front-page should appear when i open Pages->Home->Edit with elementor. As at now, editing my home page with elementor, the elementor editor is blank, i wish to import the content of the front-page.php into it.

I thought the code above the get_header() function will help me do that but it has not worked plus i vs code highlights the codes with Elementor keyword:

```
 // Initialize Elementor
 Elementor::start();
```

and displays the error: **Undefined type 'Elementor'.intelephense(1009)**

So what i want is to make my front-page.php file editable with elementor. I want that when i open Pages->Home->Edit with elementor, i should be able to see all the content in front-page.php and i be able to edit it from there.

Answer (score 0):

first, it's better to make sure this part of the code in your codes corresponds to the actual location of the Elementor plugin on your server. If the path is incorrect, Elementor won't be properly loaded.

`require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/elementor/php/elementor.php' );`

if it didn't help try to update your PHP version. Check that you have a compatible version of PHP installed. Elementor recommends using PHP 7.4 or higher.